# Polygon interpolation neighbour average?

Tags: polygon, vector, interpolation, nodata, average

I am trying to estimate empty values based on a polygon layer we received from another study. Is there a way to calculate an average value for polygon A based on neighbours B,C, etc that border it?

I thought about converting polygons to points and interpolating, but thought there may be another method of doing this.

Photo attached for reference

[image]

Comment: How does this picture help to understand your issue?

Comment: A complete description of the software in use and steps taken is necessary as well.

Comment: I figured my issue was pretty straight forward- I just couldn't find the tool (using arcmap 10.4) to implement it. blue polygons are known averages that I would like to use to estimate empty cells. I think I will just convert to point and use kriging interpolation

Comment: Essentially, I am wondering if there is a way to perform interpolation using polygons rather than points